# How to convert live image url into blob in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Im working in angular 7 and my requirement is i need to get `Width`, `Height` and `Size (in how much kb or mb)` of the image and also im trying  to convert it into `blob`.

I tried with below code but im not getting exact output:

```
var img_url = "http://snook.ca/files/mootools_83_snookca.png";


 var blob = new Blob([img_url]);

 let reader = new FileReader;

 reader.readAsDataURL(blob); // read file as data url
 reader.onload = () => { // when file has loaded
    console.log(reader.result)
    var img:any = new Image();
    img.src = reader.result;

    img.onload = () => {

      this.uploaded_image_width = img.width; //to get image width
      this.uploaded_image_height = img.height;  //to get image height           

      this.uploaded_image_url = reader.result; //to get blob image
      console.log(reader.result)          
    };          
  }
```

When im consoling the blob data is coming wrong (`console.log(reader.result)`) and inside `img.onload` function is not executing.

I referred this fiddle to achieve this :
http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9mg5sf7o/

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: You have to set the source of your image to load it. `onload` is called only when the image has a src. The issue here is that you have set the source BEFORE declaring the hook : move the line BELOW the hook, and you should be fine !

Comment: That was for Audio rather than Image, but really it's just the same.

Comment: Im using Angular 7 @TheParam

Comment: Please see my question clearly it's not same @Kaiido

Comment: The problem for me is the image is not in my local or uploaded one it's in live @Kaiido

Comment: The problem is that you are asking 3 questions in a single one... To get a Blob from this URL would require that the target server allows you to perform ajax requests, then that's just a matter of fetch(url).then(r=>r.blob) I added yet another link about this part of your question, but once again for it to succeed the target server must allow you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this way. i hope it helps you out

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    alert( this.width+' '+ this.height );
};
img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-1.jpg";
```

Comment: How can i get blob value of that image ??

Comment: first you need to convert image to base64 and then base64 to blob here is the example lin for converting a image to blob: https://gist.github.com/davoclavo/4424731